# How to save 'No data value' to a QGIS layer style properties?

Tags: qgis, style

I have many raster tif files (100+) I found this link to the MultiQml plugin very helpful, from this post: [Can I change style properties of several layers simultaneously?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/can-i-change-properties-of-several-layers-simultaneously)

However the 'No data' values does not seem to be saved with the style? Is there a way to do this? Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it, although it is not via the QGIS styles.

By **doing a translate (convert format) step in QGIS, one can assign the *no data* values,** which can be done in batch mode.

When the images are opened, the no data values all appear transparent, which is what I aimed to achieve in the first place.

This could possible be added in the styles options, but there's possibly a good reason why it's in a separate tab within layer properties.