# Remove unwanted white bands when raster layer are overlapping

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.4

In my project when raster layers are overlapping a white band appears the edge of the top layer.

How can I remove it and obtain a seamless overlapping of the raster ?

(I have try to built a vrt with those layers but the with bands remained)

I am working with QGIS 2.4

*Here is a example of the phenomena (each layer has 10% transparency)*
[image: white band on overlapping raster]

*Here is the gdalinfo output of one of the raster*

`Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vdata/scot_009h_georef.tif
Size is 5985, 2349
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-3.873394354081865,58.119237085214102)
Pixel Size = (0.000601740178426,-0.000601740178426)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -3.8733944,  58.1192371) (  3d52'24.22"W, 58d 7' 9.25"N)
Lower Left  (  -3.8733944,  56.7057494) (  3d52'24.22"W, 56d42'20.70"N)
Upper Right (  -0.2719794,  58.1192371) (  0d16'19.13"W, 58d 7' 9.25"N)
Lower Right (  -0.2719794,  56.7057494) (  0d16'19.13"W, 56d42'20.70"N)
Center      (  -2.0726869,  57.4124932) (  2d 4'21.67"W, 57d24'44.98"N)
Band 1 Block=5985x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=5985x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=5985x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0`

Comment: Is it always white? (255,255,255) You can use srcnodata in the building of the VRT.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a `gdalinfo` report for one of the rasters.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: Yes, the edge is always white. One borders almost each raster.

Comment: @Luke: I added gdalinfo output in the question.

Comment: Have you tried adding a no data value (perhaps 255, maybe 0) in the raster properties transparency setting?

Comment: @johns: Tried and it work. I had a nodata value = 0, otherwise I had in addition to the white edge, a black one. I added 255 to  "Additional No Value" and the white edge has disappeared. Is it possible to apply the change to all layer at once ?

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/can-i-change-properties-of-several-layers-simultaneously  I know ArcMap has a customization that provides for a default display of background and no data values, but a quick look at my QGIS didn't show that option.  Others probably know better.

Comment: The nodata value does not seem to be saved in a qml file (style). Therefore multiQML is not helping in my case.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

You have discovered one option - adding 255 to the "Additional No Value" in Layer Properties/Transparency.

**Option 2**

Another option is to use a VRT, define 255 as the source nodata value and define 0 as the VRT no data value using [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html).

For example:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 255 -vrtnodata 0 out.vrt in.tif
```

To do this on all tiffs in a folder, use something like the following (assuming you are using a bash shell on OSX/Linux/Unix based on the path in your `gdalinfo` output):

```
for f in *.tif; do gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 255 -vrtnodata 0 "${f%.*}".vrt "$f";  done
```

**Option 3**

A third option that will actually crop the white collars permanently and not turn non-collar white pixels to NoData is the GDAL [`nearblack`](http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) utility.

For example:

```
nearblack -of gtiff -nb 0 -color white -near 0 -o decollar.tif collar.tif
```

To do this on all tiffs in a folder, use something like the following:

```
for f in *.tif; do nearblack -of gtiff -nb 0 -color white -near 0 -o "${f%.*}"-decollared.tif "$f";  done
```

*Note `"${f%.*}"` is bash parameter expansion syntax to get the filename without the extension.*

Comment: Actually adding 255 in "Additionnal No Value" in the layer worked only for the individual layer, and in the project overview. When I built the VRT afterwards, the white lines came back. I will try your proposal when I get again access to the computer in 2 weeks.   My other concern is by doing this, I alter the content of the raster deleting the real white inside the raster, whereas the white borders are not present in the individual raster but only around the area where 2 rasters overlap, and on the top layer. Is this concern relevant ?

Comment: @FlyingGman Yes, that's because the "Additionnal No Value" is a per-layer setting. Yes, _all_ white values will be set as NoData. I've edited my question to add another option.

Comment: I found the origin of these white border: in the initial jpg scan a fine white border of 45 pixels was included during in the scan process by the machine. After georeferencing, this border is a bit deformed. Once all the files have been georeferenced, it is too time consuming the crop the individual raster and restart the georeferencing. I think your option 3 can work, I need to find a color not present in the raster to fill this border, and set this value to no value as you explained.