# QGIS 3 changing layer CRS for multiple layers simultaneously

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, batch

I have about 30 layers. Each of them has project CRS EPSG:4326, which requires change to EPSG:3857.

I know how to do it, which also has been explained here:

[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis|](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/changing-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis%7C)

Unfortunately, I would like to do these steps for my all layers.

I tried to find some way, and the hints below put me on the right track

[Change style properties of several layers simultaneously?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/change-style-properties-of-several-layers-simultaneously)

where I tried 2 options visible below.

[image]

Unfortunately, none of them was working.

Is there any way to at least copy the CRS settings for the layers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group all layers you want to change, right click the group and then "Set group CRS" should do what you asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware: you want to **reproject** your layer or **change the CRS** of the layer? That are two fundamentally different things and the linked post presents options for both: that could lead to confusion.

Normally, you should [**not change CRS**, but reproject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814) (click the link to see why).

To **reproject multiple layers at once**, run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Reproject Layer` and check the box next to `Run as Batch Process…` (bottom left). Fill in the dialog window that opens (see screenshot).

If you  really want to **batch-assign a new layer CRS**, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Assign projection` and again run it as batch process.

Projections are not part of the style, that's why you can't use the approach with Copy style.

[image]

**Edit**

By the way: don't confuse layer- and project-CRS, that are complete different things! You write:

> ...30 layers. Each of them has project CRS EPSG:4326, which requires
> change to EPSG:3857.

If you want to **change the project CRS**, simply do that at the bootom right of your QGIS window, no need to change anything for the layers. Make yourself comfortable with the difference of layer- vs. project CRS, [see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392388/88814).

So basically, you should differentiate between:

1. Reproject a layer
2. Assign (change) a layer CRS
3. Change project CRS

Comment: I just wanted to change the layer CRS without reprojection. Is something like this possible with the batch process?

Comment: Run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Assign projection` in batch mode, see updated answer.

Comment: Could you tell me why I shouldn't just change CRS but reproject?

Comment: The reason is explained in detail in the link in my answer: change CRS is made for data that comes with no (or wrong) CRS definition. When you "change"/set the CRS of a correctly positioned layer, it will probably be placed in a wrong place on earth. A layer in `EPSG:4326`, changed to `EPSG:3857`, will show a point with geographic coordinates 10° E, 45° N (=northern Italy) somewhere in the Atlantic south of Ghana: coordinates are interpreted as 10 meters east of the prime meridian and 45 meters north of the Equator. That's probably not what you want. That's why you should reproject.

Comment: Don't confuse layer- and project-CRS - see updated answer. After re-reading your question, I'm nor really sure what you want to change and why you want to set a different CRS for your layer. Be aware not to make wrong settings.